# How to make a Hybrid App using PhoneGap

Tags: android, html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I know that I need to edit the `index.html` file and `config.xml` file.

I made a Hybrid App by adding this line in my `index.html` file, and it works.

```
        <iframe src="http://example.com"  frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%">
```

**The problem**

I have some external URL's on my website like: `Login With Facebook` `IMDB page of a movie`. I want those links to open inside the App.

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Try using inAppBrowser http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html It helps to open external url inside the app

Comment: @Toby you need to set allow access origin to '*' in config.xml